# Is leveraging passing by reference in Angular 2 considered bad practice?

Tags: angular, data-binding

If you bind an object in Angular 2, for example

```
<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
```

then it is bound by reference. Therefore it doesn't matter whether you'll update **a field** of `myObject` in the child or the parent, it will always be updated everywhere. On the other hand, if you swap the entire object in the child, the reference is broken and it's not updated anymore. In the Angular 2 tutorial, they update the name of `selectedHero` in the `my-hero-detail` component (i.e. **child component**) and everything is updated view-wide. But isn't this contradictory to what the pointy brackets `[]` are meant for? From the Angular 2 docs:

> [target] = "expression" is one-way, from data source to view target

But it's not one way at all, if I can actually update the fields in the child component. Isn't this kind of a trap, if you update the fields of a bound object, it's updated everywhere but when you replace the entire object, then it's not updated? And even worse, if you replace the entire object once in the child, also the fields aren't updated anymore, so you have to be aware what the entire controller does?! Why doesn't Angular 2 just make a copy of the object, so that it actually can't be modified by the child? For performance reasons, I guess? But then, when someone replaces the entire object, the app will be broken, for example:

```
  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.hero) {
      const name = this.hero.name;
      this.hero = {
        name: name
      } 
    }
  }
```

and then the parent isn't updated anymore, and you have to search why. So it's really confusing for developers as they always have to be aware "am I updating a primitive or an entire object vs am I updating the field of an entire object? Has someone broken the reference to the parent? Because then I can't rely anymore that it's bound by reference."

I've seen people make copies themselves in Angular 1 using `angular.copy` on each child component, but that seems rather cumbersome too, because if that would be best practice why doesn't angular handle it. So I can't really imagine leveraging passing by reference to be considered bad practice since Angular 2 does it in it's tutorials. But then how do you avoid the pitfalls mentioned?